# Bootstrap Fixed Navigation and Parallax: Highlight does not works

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm working on [this website](http://develop.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/) builted using Bootstrap.
As you can see i've a Fixed Top Nav Bar and the Homepage is a "One Scroll" page. What i need is to **highlight** this 2 anchorpoints when they are **active**:

`<li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ark">Architektur</a></li>
 <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ausstattung">Ausstattung</a></li>`

With this CSS Style:

`background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #009ee0 !important;`

I tried with [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp) with no results.

Any tips?

EDIT:

I just added this:

`<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">`

And works, ut as soon i click on

`<li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ark">Architektur</a></li>
 <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ausstattung">Ausstattung</a></li>`

the `a`link has a Grey Background. But as soon i click somewehere then looks perfect. Is a JS problem?

Comment: i think on your body tag  data-spy="" data-target=""  are missing .. put those

Comment: @RamanaaGj i just added it, but if you check my homepage the "Home" link is always active. How come?

Comment: remove selected tag in home div i mean in this line `class="page-scroll selected"` remove `selected`

Comment: good you remove it ..seen your website now working fine .. if you got it click upvote button in comment

Comment: @RamanaaGj yeah, now it works but i have a problem. As son i click on the `a` link the background is Grey but as soon i click somewhere then works. Is a JS problem?

Comment: no it was caused by css in your css file put this code `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover{ background-color: #fff;}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there are a few things to address here with your code.  First you need to add the body scrollspy tag.  So it will look like this:

```
<body  data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="50">
```

Then you have the id #navbar stated twice.  If you resize your window to a mobile size you will see that your collapsable menu doesn't collapse.  This is because you have your data-target set to #navbar and you have this stated twice.  It doesn't have anything to do with scrollspy but I figured I would give you a heads up anyway to save you a future headache and we will set your button to target the .navbar-collapse.  Then remove the class of page scroll from everything except the href's that have an anchor tag in it.  Long story short your navbar should look like the following:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="selected" href="http://develop.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ark">Architektur</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ausstattung">Ausstattung</a></li>  
        <li><a href="/table.html">Wohnungen</a></li>
        <li><a href="/lage.html">Lage</a></li>
        <li><a href="/galerie.html">Galerie</a></li>
        <li><a href="/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Then I always like to give the following jquery code because it gives you more control over the scrollspy plugin like how fast the animation is and better control over the top offset so add this as well:

```
$(".navbar a.page-scroll").on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var hash = this.hash;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 50
  }, 800, function(){
    window.location.hash = hash;
  });
});
```

So now your body is targeting the #navbar and your collapsable menu will work and your markup will be correct.

Here is a fiddle to show you this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/w2sf6k1u/)

Comment: Than you so much! Now it also wark on mobile. But i have a question: Why as soon i  click on the anchor point link it's like the background is setted on grey and the font-color on black and as soon i click somewhere then it's works?

Comment: This is because of the a:focus css that bootstrap has set.  You can change this by adding custom css to .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover{your css here}. This will change all of the active classes to be the same on focus and hover.

Comment: Also I see that you may want to keep your custom css for the home li because scrollspy will remove the active class from it when you scroll down to the first section so maybe give it your selected class again so that people can tell they are on the homepage and I will edit this in my answer as well.  Also if this fixed your problem consider checking it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your css

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
  background: yellow !important;}
```

and you are done,